# Generate reports from data that was removed?

Tags: mysql, database, report

I need to generate a report which shows subscriptions for a object for a specific period. The problem is the objects on which a subscription is taken can be removed. So if the object is removed then i cannot generate a report for it anymore, simply because it is not known in the database anymore.

My current solution would be to introduce a "deleted" tag/db column that indicates if a object was removed. This way i can create reports even for removed objects.

This works nicely, but when the reports get more complex you will get more objects/tables with the "deleted" column, which might become less manageable.

Other solution i thought about are:

- create reports when object is removed. Problem here is when new reports are introduced, new reports cannot be created from removed object.
- save removed data to another form/table/format. Problem here is that you might not have saved enough for future reports and it is a a lot more work.

Any ideas on this subject? Or maybe even other, better, solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question: i bumped into the soft delete while doing further research and there is a lot of information regarding soft delete and it seems to be a good solution for the problem.